# Matlab unique() vs Excel Remove Duplicate

Tags: excel, matlab, duplicates

I am experiencing a very strange issue where `Matlab` `unique(A, 'rows', 'stable')` and `Excel - Remove Duplicates` do not yield the same results based on a large file `(7020 * 132)`.
This is astonishing to the extent that on a little matrix:

`A= [2 2 2 2; 4 6 0 9; 2 2 2 2 ; -1 -3 8 15]`

`unique(A, 'rows', 'stable')` yields `[2 2 2 2; 4 6 0 9; -1 -3 8 15]` that is correct. However, on a  `(7020 * 132)` file, the `Matlab` `unique(FileasMatrix_ofDouble_type, 'rows', 'stable')` command does not find any duplicates whereas `Excel` finds `5263` duplicates (duplicates based on the first column) that are also spotted quickly (with eyes) while opening the file.

Thus I wonder whether someone has experienced similar issues for sharing purposes. Best

*Ps: there is unfortunately no option to upload the dataset.xlsx so as to share this strange phenomenon*

Comment: “duplicates based on the first column”. This is not what `unique` does. The whole row is compared.

Comment: Thanks Cris. I was expecting both methods to reconcile. It's even worse to the extent that when I apply the `unique(File, 'rows', 'stable')` on my dataset up to the `column 120`, the command does find duplicates. However from `column [121; end]` the `Matlab command` does not find the remaining obvious duplicates that `Excel` does .

Comment: Do you have integers or floating point values?

Comment: Yes I have both. I did think about potential effects of `truncated values` until I had copied the `dataset` the `Excel` and figured out they were only up to `4 decimals` for the f`loating` data which did not prevent Excel from removing the `duplicate` rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *seems* from your description that you expected `unique` to remove rows where the first element is the same. This is not how `unique(___,'rows')` operates. However, we can replicate this operation in MATLAB.

From the documentation to [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html):

> `[C,ia,ic] = unique(___)` also returns index vectors `ia` and `ic` using any of the previous syntaxes.
>   If A is a vector, then `C = A(ia)` and `A = C(ic)`.

Thus, if we apply `unique` to the first column of the matrix, it will return, in `ia`, the indices of the rows you'd like to keep. Regular indexing will then do so. For example:

```
A = randi(4,10,6);
[~,index] = unique(A(:,1),'stable');
B = A(index,:);
```

Comment: Thank you very much Cris. Your solution is a good way around to the extent that my `dataset` should not retrieve in any circumstances `duplicate records` based on the first column (`date` converted into `serial number`), disregarding the values held in columns `2:end`, which in my case are all identical for the `non-indexed/removed row`.